# How to create dynamic node name of xml using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new in xsl field. I have following xml format.

```
 <root>
    <docs>
      <doc>
      <actor_name_1>aaa</actor_name_1>
     <url_1>dddd</url_1>
     </doc>
    <doc>
     <actor_name_2>bbb</actor_name_2>
     <url_2>dddd</url_2>
    </doc>
    <doc>
       <actor_name_3>ccc</actor_name_3>
      <url_3>dddd</url_3>
    </doc>
    </docs>
    </root>
```

I want get value of `<actor_name_>` nodes with dynamic value of numberic (like 1,2,etc) in xslt. LIke as

```
<xsl:for-each select="//root/docs/doc">
<xsl:value-of select="actors_name_">position()</xsl:value-of>
<xsl:value-of select="url_">position()</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output will be..

```
 Actor 1 aaaa  url 1 ddddd
 Actor 2 bbb   url 2 ddddd
 Actor 3 ccc   url 3 sss
```

Please help me. How to get dynamic value of nodes?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result. Also explain why you need to number the `actor_name` nodes, when they are already numbered (not to mention that such numbering is bad practice).

Comment: Yes, It is bad practice. But xml is not created by me, it is provide by some client. I added output. Please help me. Thanks for comment.

Comment: The logic of the required transformation is still not entirely clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `starts-with()` function to check the node name. Below is the code snippet that will help you get all the values from `<actor_name_*>` and `<url_*>` nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//root/docs/doc">
            <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="actorName" select="./*[starts-with(local-name(), 'actor_name_')]" />
            <xsl:variable name="url" select="./*[starts-with(local-name(), 'url_')]" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Actor ', $index, ' ', $actorName, ' url ', $index, ' ', $url, '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also as suggested by @michael, please check the requirement of appending the number to the nodes as the nodes are repeating within in the same parent i.e. `<doc>` and the numbering is not necessary.

Comment: #Aniket Thanks for answer. Please explain according to my xml now.

Comment: Please share how your output XML will look like. Based on the output XML, a concrete answer can be shared.

Comment: I added output, which i want. Please explain it .

Comment: Hey Aniket, This code gives only one row. Please suggest, what i do for next row.

Comment: The answer has been updated to provide the complete XSLT. You need to do some reading to understand XSLT.

Comment: **This is not a valid XSLT stylesheet.** `xsl:value-of` cannot be a child of `xsl:text`.

Comment: I have made the changes accordingly. However I did not find any problems during the transformation even though the `<xsl:value-of>` was retained as a child of `<xsl:text>`. Thanks for the update though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear. If - as it seems - you want to produce a tab-separated text file as the output, you could probably do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="docs/doc">
        <xsl:text>Actor </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="*[1]" />
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>url </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="*[2]" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the given example, the result will be:

```
Actor 1 aaa url 1   dddd
Actor 2 bbb url 2   dddd
Actor 3 ccc url 3   dddd
```